# Show the MySQL value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a table which will show all the months of the year, and their values​​.

Always will be shown the current year, and then by months of the year.. there would:

```
+------+-----+--------+--------+---------+
| YEAR | MES | ENTRY  | OUTPUT | BALANCE |
+------+-----+--------+--------+---------+
| 2013 | Jan | 250.55 | -50.00 |  200.55 |
| 2013 | Feb | 0:00   |-100.00 |  100.00 |
+------+-----+--------+--------+---------+
```

What I'm not getting is like the example of FEBRUARY, for there future release that can be done in BD, even if you have zero input, but output has, I can not show.

Discovering this site, and I'm trying to do online, see: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa97b/2

```
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsAnoAtualEntrada = "SELECT ID_FinanE, SUM(valor) AS SomaEntradaAtual, data FROM financ_receita WHERE YEAR(data) = ".date("Y")." GROUP BY MONTH(data)";
$rsAnoAtualEntrada = mysql_query($query_rsAnoAtualEntrada, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsAnoAtualEntrada = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAnoAtualEntrada);
$totalRows_rsAnoAtualEntrada = mysql_num_rows($rsAnoAtualEntrada);


mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$query_rsAnoAtualSaida = "SELECT ID_FinanS, SUM(valor) AS SomaSaidaAtual, data FROM financ_despesa WHERE YEAR(data) = ".date("Y")." GROUP BY MONTH(data)";
$rsAnoAtualSaida = mysql_query($query_rsAnoAtualSaida, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsAnoAtualSaida = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAnoAtualSaida);
$totalRows_rsAnoAtualSaida = mysql_num_rows($rsAnoAtualSaida);
```

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Really unclear, I can't get the problem. Please edit your post to add detail. What "for there future release that can be done in BD, even if you have zero input, but output has, I can not show." means ?

Comment: Sorry, it's my first post here, I tried to stay neat, thanks for editing.

How am Brazilian, and use google translator, you can get a little confusing, but I'll try to explain very simple.


I always want to show the values ​​of input and output of the current year.
Then show the months in sequence according to the BD and its added values​​.

January
February
March
.
.
.

In the month of jajeiro would get all the added values ​​that were recorded in January, and so on.


Unable to explain it?


Thank you.

Comment: In your future projects, try to use English and not your mother tongue in your code. Because it's harder to understand what you try to do when we don't understand your comments and variable names...

Comment: True friend, sorry, I'll do the next best.

Comment: Your fiddle is not  compatible with your code example, can you try to be more specific on what is the input and what is the expected output. And strip down your extra code in the Fiddle that have nothing to do with the question and try to translate them in English. Example "Entry" === Fiddle "SOMAENTRADAATUAL" ?

Comment: financ_despesa EXPENSE = (Output)
financ_receita = INCOME (In)

Comment: SOMAENTRADAATUAL = ENTRY

Comment: SOMASAIDAATUAL = OUTPUT

Comment: @Tiago Thank you, sir! Na proxima vez que voce tiver que procurar uma solução, favor tentar separar suas perguntas para cada problema distinto. Por exemplo, em vez de adicionar a esse post, faça uma nova pergunta especifica sobre o problema de “PREVIOUS BALANCE”.  Favor tambem incluir o maximo do “code” que for possivel. Isso mostra que voce esta’ tentando resolver seu problema e tambem ajudaria com a barreira da lingua. (OBS. Eu nao falo Portugues – um amigo traduziu isso para mim!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking for is a listing of all months in a given year, then their sum (soma) values for `SomaEntradaAtual` and `SomaSaidaAtual`, even if no records for a particular month exist?  If so, you could try the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
     2013 AS Year, 
     m.month AS Month, 
     fr.SomaEntradaAtual AS Entry, 
     fd.SomaSaidaAtual AS Output, 
     IFNULL(fr.SomaEntradaAtual,0) - IFNULL(fd.SomaSaidaAtual,0) AS Balance,
     @running_total := @running_total + IFNULL(fr.SomaEntradaAtual,0) - IFNULL(fd.SomaSaidaAtual,0) AS Cumulative_Balance
 FROM
 FROM (
       SELECT 'Jan' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Feb' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Mar' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Apr' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'May' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jun' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jul' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Aug' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Sep' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Oct' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Nov' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Dec' AS MONTH
      ) AS m
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Month(DATA) AS rmonth, SUM(valor) AS SomaEntradaAtual,
    DATA FROM financ_receita WHERE YEAR(DATA) = 2013
    GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) AS fr
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' 2013'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(fr.DATA)
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Month(DATA) AS dmonth, SUM(valor) AS SomaSaidaAtual,
       DATA FROM financ_despesa WHERE YEAR(DATA) = 2013
       GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) AS fd
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' 2013'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(fd.DATA)
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dca67/27

Basically, you're creating a dummy table of every month, then LEFT JOINing your `financ_despesa` and `financ_receita` tables with the sum values for that given month.

To use this in your PHP, simply replace the `2013` with a variable:

```
$year = "2013";
$sql = "    SELECT 
     $year AS Year, 
     m.month AS Month, 
     fr.SomaEntradaAtual AS Entry, 
     fd.SomaSaidaAtual AS Output, 
     IFNULL(fr.SomaEntradaAtual,0) - IFNULL(fd.SomaSaidaAtual,0) AS Balance,
     @running_total := @running_total + IFNULL(fr.SomaEntradaAtual,0) - IFNULL(fd.SomaSaidaAtual,0) AS Cumulative_Balance
 FROM (
       SELECT 'Jan' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Feb' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Mar' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Apr' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'May' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jun' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Jul' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Aug' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Sep' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Oct' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Nov' AS MONTH
       UNION SELECT 'Dec' AS MONTH
      ) AS m
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Month(DATA) AS rmonth, SUM(valor) AS SomaEntradaAtual,
    DATA FROM financ_receita WHERE YEAR(DATA) = $year
    GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) AS fr
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' $year'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(fr.DATA)
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Month(DATA) AS dmonth, SUM(valor) AS SomaSaidaAtual,
       DATA FROM financ_despesa WHERE YEAR(DATA) = $year
       GROUP BY MONTH(DATA)) AS fd
ON MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(m.month, ' $year'),'%M %Y')) = MONTH(fd.DATA)
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r";
```

(Answer updated to include `Balance` value as well as `Cumulative_Balance` and match expected results table more accurately.)

Comment: +1 for decrypting his question and for mentioning on the fly dummy tables using SELECT UNION.

Comment: Amazing!, I will test now!

Comment: Thanks! I left out the bit about `balance`...

Comment: That was going to ask now, I need to show also the balance, see a picture of how I'm riding http://prntscr.com/28fhbj


In the image the word "SALDO ANTERIOR" means (PREVIOUS BALANCE). This value is similar to the current balance, but the previous month.

How do I use Dreamwaver, it is possible to assemble this code mean http://prntscr.com/28fiza ?

Comment: @Tiago Just updated my answer to include the `Balance` value. As far as the PREVIOUS BALANCE question, you should create a new question. (Also, please mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem!)

Comment: Friend, was missing from the calculation "SALDO ANTERIOR" means (PREVIOUS BALANCE). This value is similar to the current balance, but the previous month

Comment: Ok, I understand, but soon you will need to try this yourself!! Please see my edits, and please mark my answer as "correct" if it works for you. I have added a new column `Cumulative_Balance`.

Comment: @KristenWaite Hello how are you? I am updating this same select for the current versions and am having this problem. `Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sitepara_bd.financ_despesa.data' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`, Can you help me again?